# Linux using the RANDOM function

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I received an assignment in school where I'm suppose to generate output in a random color if specified. My program doesn't generate the color that I would like it to when the RANDOM option is selected.

My input to the program is:

```
echoc RANDOM|colour string
```

And my code looks like:

```
    declare -A colours=( 
[black]="0;30" [red]="0;31" [green]="0;32" [yellow]="0;33" [blue]="0;34" [magenta]="0;35" [cyan]="0;36" [white]="0;37"
[BLACK]="1;30" [RED]="1;31" [GREEN]="1;32" [YELLOW]="1;33" [BLUE]="1;34" [MAGENTA]="1;35" [CYAN]="1;36" [WHITE]="1;37")


if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: echoc COLOUR|RANDOM STRING"
  exit 1
fi

regex='^red$|^green$|^yellow$|^blue$|^magenta$|^cyan$|^white|^black$'
shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then        
  printf '\033[%sm' ${colours[$1]}
  shift
  printf '%s\033[0m\n' "$*"
  exit 0
elif [[ $1 == "RANDOM" ]]; then   
  printf '\033[%sm' ${colours[$((RANDOM%8+1))]}
  shift
  printf '%s\033[0m\n' "$*"
  exit 3
else
  echo COLOUR must be one of 'red|green|yellow|blue|magenta|cyan|white|RANDOM'
  exit 2
fi
```

Comment: That's because when you're calling `${colours[$((RANDOM%8+1))]}` bash will try to find the `key` `1` or `2` or ... or `8` in the associative array `colours`... which doesn't exist. Good luck. Btw, I don't really understand all the downvotes! Your question is not _please do my homework_. Your question is: _I've done this, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong_. I'm sure if you hadn't mentioned the words _assignment in school_ you wouldn't have got all these downvotes...

Comment: Thanks and yea, im not asking u guys to rewrite it, or even write the correct line, just point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Would this be better because hopefully derp will have a value of 1 to 8 and then i can search the array for that parameter, derp=$(($RANDOM%8+1))    
        printf '\033[%sm' ${colours[$derp]}

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. You need to build an array, the fields of which are the keys of `colours`, then take a random element of this array and the corresponding value in `colours`. Good luck.

Comment: Okay so i added, [1]="0;30" [2]="0;31" ... [8]="0;37" in the array, no cookie tho. thanks for all your help though :)

Comment: FINALLY turns out all i needed was to add "" around my variable derp. Thanks gniour for your help.

Comment: You're not respecting the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle! `:)`. Exercise: count how many times you write the same things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare -A colours=(

[1]="0;30" [2]="0;31" [3]="0;32" [4]="0;33" [5]="0;34" [6]="0;35" [7]="0;36" [8]="0;37"
[black]="0;30" [red]="0;31" [green]="0;32" [yellow]="0;33" [blue]="0;34" [magenta]="0;35" [cyan]="0;36" [white]="0;37"
[BLACK]="1;30" [RED]="1;31" [GREEN]="1;32" [YELLOW]="1;33" [BLUE]="1;34" [MAGENTA]="1;35" [CYAN]="1;36" [WHITE]="1;37")


if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then

    echo "Usage: echoc COLOUR|RANDOM STRING"

    exit 1

fi


regex='^red$|^green$|^yellow$|^blue$|^magenta$|^cyan$|^white|^black$'

shopt -s nocasematch

if [[ $1 =~ $regex ]]; then

    printf '\033[%sm' ${colours[$1]}

    shift

    printf '%s\033[0m\n' "$*"

    exit 0

elif [[ $1 == "RANDOM" ]]; then

derp=$(($RANDOM%8+1))

    printf '\033[%sm' ${colours["$derp"]}

    shift

    printf '%s\033[0m\n' "$*"

    exit 3

    else

    echo COLOUR must be one of 'red|green|yellow|blue|magenta|cyan|white|RANDOM'

    exit 2

fi
```